# How to return JSON with object name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How to add `object` name in the front when I am returning?

```
 public IEnumerable<Institutions> Get(string subscriptionDate)
 {
     return institutionses;
 }
```

JSON Retrurn

```
[{
    "institutionId": "9041765",
    "institutionName": "University of Melbourne",
    "isConsortia": false,
    "consortiaParentId": null,        
},
{
    "institutionId": "9043242",
    "institutionName": "University of texas",
    "isConsortia": false,
    "consortiaParentId": null,        
}]
```

But expecting

```
{
    "institutions": [{
             "institutionId": "9041765",
             "institutionName": "University of Melbourne",
             "isConsortia": false,
             "consortiaParentId": null,        
         },
        {
             "institutionId": "9043242",
             "institutionName": "University of texas",
             "isConsortia": false,
             "consortiaParentId": null,        
       }]
  }
```

Comment: How do you serialize it? Please, share the code

Comment: Your method is returning a collection, you need to return an Object.

Comment: put it inside a ``RootObject`` and return it, like ``public class RootObject{ public IEnumerable<Institution> institutions { get; set; }}``

Comment: @Sajid it worked

Answer (score 2):

@sajid said

put it inside a RootObject and return it, like

```
public class RootObject{ public IEnumerable<Institution> institutions { get; set; }}
```